# Why is "[COUNT (*): 0]" returned instead of just "0" when executing sql query in groovy?

Tags: sql, groovy

Why is "[COUNT (*): 0]" returned instead of just "0" when executing sql query in groovy? What can I do to return only a number?

```
            def res = sql.firstRow("""SELECT count(*) FROM bd.pas WHERE INN = ?
AND SYSDATE >= RECDATEBEGIN AND SYSDATE < RECDATEEND AND NVL(DLL, 0) = 0
""",['test'])
            println(res)
```

Comment: Noting to do with `Java`. Removing tag.

Answer (score 1):

Use an alias in your query:

```
def res = sql.firstRow("""SELECT count(*) as num FROM bd.pas WHERE INN = ?
AND SYSDATE >= RECDATEBEGIN AND SYSDATE < RECDATEEND AND NVL(DLL, 0) = 0
""",['test'])
```

and then read the specific field:

```
println(res.num)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `firstRow()` returns a `GroovyRowResult` which is essentially a `Map`.

That's why you get `[COUNT (*): 0]`.

To get a number only out of it you can do:

```
def res = sql.firstRow("""SELECT count(*) FROM bd.pas ...""",['test']).values().first()
```